# What does 'Equal Opportunity Employer' mean?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I saw some job postings in Stack Overflow Jobs on which the company claims to be an 'Equal Opportunity Employer', but they ask for US or Europe citizenship for the position. Thus, not all candidates have the same opportunities.

Is this contradictory or there is a formal definition of the sentence 'Equal Opportunity Employer'?

Comment: [Workplace.SE covers this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3960/what-is-an-equal-opportunity-employer)

Comment: That answers the question, thanks.

Comment: When downsizing, employee names are drawn from a hat:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a term of art in United States federal employment regulations to refer to hiring expectations mandated by law, and thus is [a common fixture in job postings for US companies](https://blog.ongig.com/diversity-and-inclusion/eeo-statement-samples).

The term has its origins in the US Civil Rights Act of 1964, which first established equal opportunity employment as a federal law. This legislation made it illegal for companies to discriminate against employees or potential employees on the basis of race, color, sex, religion, or national origin. Title VII of this law established the Equal Employment Opportunity Commission (EEOC), whose charter is to investigate claims of employment discrimination. In 1972, the Equal Employment Opportunity Act amended Title VII to further expand the EEOC's powers, amplifying its authority to enforce employment discrimination laws.

Since the initial protections guaranteed in 1964, additional laws have added to the protected categories, including an expansion of "sex" to include pregnancy issues, sexual orientation, and gender identity, as well as adding explicit protections for disabilities, age, and genetic issues.

So, in the US, it's illegal for employers to discriminate against employees or potential employees on any of these basis. As such, you might think that the claim to be an "Equal Opportunity Employer" is mere noise, since it could be taken as implied. Unfortunately, there are exceptions to the anti-discrimination statutes that can be claimed by employers under certain circumstances. Stating explicitly that one is an "Equal Opportunity Employer" announces that these exemptions have not been claimed. The EEOC also recommends including the phrase to encourage members of historically marginalized groups to apply to jobs.

See also: [Equal employment opportunity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_employment_opportunity) on Wikipedia.

To answer your question directly: the phrase "Equal Opportunity Employer" does not establish *citizenship* as a protected category. National origin is protected, but US companies are free to discriminate based upon citizenship. In fact, federal law *requires* this discrimination in certain cases, like for companies who work with the military and/or national secrets.

Comment: And veteran (US military) status I believe...